# BigDecimal.valueOf(n).toPlainString() is not giving exact value

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

I am taking a double value(generated by a different method) and i want to extract number of trailing zeros from it.One way to do is by converting it into String and then doing operations on it but i am getting values in scientific notation for eg that method generated factorial of 60 i.e 8.320987112741392E81 as it is in scientific notation i am unable to do string operations on it. I googled about this and found out that using  BigDecimal.valueOf(n).toPlainString()
i can get exact number but unfortunately i am getting this
 //8320987112741392000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
whereas the correct precise answer is
//8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000

Anyone know how to tackle this problem

```
public class Factorial {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int t = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        double num = Double.parseDouble(bf.readLine());
        System.out.println("fact ans" + factorial(num));
        System.out.println(z(factorial(num)));
    }

}

public static Double factorial(Double n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return 1D;

    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);

}

public static int z(Double n) {

    System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(n).toPlainString());
    return 1;

}
```

}

Comment: If you want an exact number why do you use double? Floating point numbers like double are known to be imprecise.

Comment: So i guess i should use long?

Comment: No, you should use ***BigDecimal.***

Answer (score 3):

You store factorial in `Double` type. Obviously, it is imprecise for big values of `n`(because it is a floating-point type). Converting an imprecise value to `BigDecimal` cannot make it precise. If you want to get precise value of factorial, you'd better use `BigInteger`.